# How does EL statement: ${person.dog.name} know that attribute "person" is of type Person?

Tags: java, jsp, el

I have these pictures from Head First book:

[image]

---

[image]

I want you to pay attention to code that replaces `${person.dog.name}`. Only thing I want to know is how does it know that attribute "person" is object of type Person? Of course, `getAttribute()` returns Object, so it must be casted to Person, but how does it know that it is made from Person class?

I guess this code uses `findAttribute()` previously, to find scope where attribute with value "person" is stored. Later it tries to get it using `getAttribute()`. So after it *finds* it, it *gets* it - but it still doesn't know what it is getting in reality. So how/where did it "figure out" that it is of type Person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the EL engine sees `person` and looks it up in the glorified HashMap (which is what `request.setAttribute` is filling - that glorified hashmap).

It finds an object there, because you set it. It gets this object and invoked `.getClass()` on it, which returns `Person.class`. It then runs a capitalizer function on `dog` to produce `getDog`. It then scans for all fields using `.getFields()` as well as all methods using `.getMethods()`, looking for either a field named `dog` or a no-args instance method named `getDog`. It finds the method, and invokes it.

Repeat this principle for how it ends up dealing with the `.name` part.

Now EL has an object (the result of invoking getName on whatever object wsas returned by reflectively invoking getDog on whatever `person` was), and toStrings that into place.

I don't think it's HTML escaping it, so this is a book that is 'helpfully' informing you how to use obsolete technology (JSP) to create security holes. Great.

You got a newer book? You might wanna get something that is less than 10 years old :)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't. The properties are resolved using reflection, by looking for a method  `getDog()` on *whatever object `person` resolves to*, and then repeating that process.